# When comparing two dates, what term is best used to say that one should come before the other?

Tags: american-english, comparison

When comparing two dates, what term is best used to say that one should come before the other?

For example, a user of my application can input two dates, that form a time interval. Obviously the "start date" has to be a valid date that comes *before* the "end date", so when the user enters these wrong I show him an error message. But, since English is not my native language, I don't know that comparison term to use.

Can a date be said to be *"smaller"* than another date? Or should I use something like *"anterior"*, or *"earlier"*?

Comment: Can use *should precede*; *be earlier*; even *before*, but **not** *smaller*, *anterior* (in front of).

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable message would be:

The **Start Date** must be before the **End Date**

Other possible words are *predate* and *precede*. But the above phrase is the way it's said colloquially.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding instruction might read:

> - Enter the start date and the end date, in chronological order
> - Enter the (earlier) start date, and then the (later) end date
> - First enter the start date, and then the end date